# Weird text glitching on 16.04

Tags: graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, fonts, text

Just now, after waking my fully up-to-date install of 16.04 (updated this afternoon) from suspend, I found that a lot of text is randomly missing from certain applications. **This has happened twice before a while ago.** For example:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Logging out and back in fixed it, but I'd like to know what caused this...**

System info:

- Dell E6530
- Nvidia Prime with Nvidia disabled and only using the Intel card